# Beginning to learn Python with python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started to learn python. And surely I'm a pretty beginner (I've just walked around few steps in Java). 
Firstly, I've installed the latest version of python and started learning with *[Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/)*.

First program that I have to start with is this;

> FIRST PYTHON PROGRAM

```
SUFFIXES = {1000: ['KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'],
        1024: ['KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB', 'PiB', 'EiB', 'ZiB', 'YiB']} #Line which gives the error
def approximate_size(size, a_kilobyte_is_1024_bytes=True):
    '''Convert a file size to human-readable form.

    Keyword arguments:
    size -- file size in bytes

    a_kilobyte_is_1024_bytes -- if True (default), use multiples of 1024
    if False, use multiples of 1000
    Returns: string
    '''

    if size < 0:
        raise ValueError('number must be non-negative')

    multiple = 1024 if a_kilobyte_is_1024_bytes else 1000
    for suffix in SUFFIXES[multiple]:
        size /= multiple
        if size < multiple:
            return '{0:.1f} {1}'.format(size, suffix)
    raise ValueError('number too large')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(approximate_size(1000000000000, False))
    print(approximate_size(1000000000000))
```

I copied the whole thing to *python3.5.1 shell* and pressed *Enter*. Then I got an error and flew out all my joy with my first program.

> `SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement`

First question; Have I got the right approach to start learning python?

How I should start learning python; Any recommended free eBook?

What is the version should I use?

Comment: Give us the specific line that triggered the SyntaxError.

Comment: Also, I hope you indented your code? :) If you did, could you update the representation here so it looks exactly like you have it.

Comment: Go through the book "learn python the hrad way" ...its good for start

Comment: Lastly: usually copying the whole thing directly into the shell can cause the interpreter to misunderstand indentation marks. Try running the same program from the command line (if on Windows, simply right click and run the .py file with IDLE)

Comment: @Liongold Is it necessary to add the spaces and tabs within the code ?

Comment: @Tharindu **Very** Necessary to add **spaces** *not* tabs. JK. But yes whitespace is meaningful in python.

Comment: @Signal Thank you for the very important detail

Comment: Can anyone explain me why this question has negative reputations? Please help me to edit this question removing bugs.

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources are off topic for SO.

Comment: Thank you again for good info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error, and the way your sample code is rendered suggest that you typed all of this in as a single line ... or possibly in a way that your system treats as if it were a single line.

The first problem you're encountering is that you're trying to just paste or copy stuff without understanding what the explanation around that code example was trying to tell you to do.

Start with a simpler snippet of code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def greet(someone):
    print('Hello, %s!' % someone)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    greet('World')
```

This is almost the simplest working sample of Python code.

The first line is a special kind of comment which is recognized by Linux and other Unix-like operating systems (such as  MacOS X on Apple brand systems).  It finds any "python3" interpreter on your path and runs the rest of this code in an environment under that interpreter.

The next line starts the **def**-inition of a function, named *greet* and taking a single argument *someone*.  The next line is indented.  That indentation is how Python distinguishes that this ***print()*** line is part of the function that you're defining.

This is the part that you seem to have missed in trying to read that tutorial.  There are a number of things in Python that require that you indent a set of lines (a "suite" of code) following them.

In my example we're only defining our function to contain a single line: specifically that's a call to the **print()** function.  You can see that we're passing the **print()** function an expression as a single argument.  That expression is a bit complicated ... but it takes one string and performs the ***%*** operation on it and another string.  This "interpolation" operation searching the string on the left (an "operand") for certain patterns (denoted by % characters) and replaces those with items from the other operand (to the right of the ***%*** operator).  The effect of this is to print the string "Hello, XXXX!" ... with the XXXX replaced by whatever string was passed to our **greet()** function.

After the definition of our function I'm leaving a blank line.  That's optional, but prefer style so that the reader can easily spot where one block of code is separated from another.

The next line is "**if**" statement.  You'll see this particular line in many Python scripts.  When a Python is processing a file of source code it's doing so either as a script, a program that's being run, or by incorporating that code into some other program or script (via the ***import*** statement).  When Python is processing a file as a script then it sets a special variable named *_*_*name*_*_* (double-underscore, main, double-underscore) to the special value "*_*_*main*_*_*" (otherwise it's set of the name of the module that's being imported).

So this **if** statement will only be true when the code is being run as a script, not when the code is being imported into some other program.  In that case the next line (which must be indented) will be executed (evaluated).  That line is a call to the "**greet()**" function we defined earlier.

We could include as many other statements within this "suite" as we liked.  All of them would only be evaluated when the **if** condition is true.  The first out-dented line marks the end of the suite.  That code would be evaluated any time the code is processed (as a script or during an import operation).

The overall effect of this whole code snippet (all six lines of it) is to implement a single file which is a standalone script and a library (or Python module).  You can run this as a script by saving it in a file and passing the file's name to the Python command on your system or by marking it as "executable" (on Unix-like systems).  On MS Windows machines you would name the file with a .py filename extension and, when you installed Python, it's likely that you already have an association between that extension and the Python interpreter.

(To use this file as a module, to be able to **import** it into another Python script you'd have to add the .py extension on Unix-like systems as well; that's just the way that Python is defined to search for Python modules; though there are some more complicated options to **import** which you'll learn much later as you get more advanced).

My point here is that you can't just paste text.  You have to read and understand what the explanations around it are saying.

Try this little snippet.  Get that running.  Then go back and re-read the Dive into Python introduction again.

Comment: By the way your indentations can be spaces or tab characters ... but it's extremely important to be consistent.  Technically you can use a mixture if you insert eight spaces to represent a single [Tab] character --- but that's a very bad idea.  The recommendation is to use two or four spaces for each level of indentation.  (As you get more advanced it will be common to have three or four levels of indentation; more than five or six considered to be bad style).

Answer (score 1):

This is because Python is a scripting language which is based on interpreter, which can execute the single statement at a time.
This error is due because you have copied the multiple statements and make interpreter misunderstood that this whole program is a single statement.

To solve this you have to copy the whole program in the new file then save the file using the .py extension then run that file in the IDLE interpreter.

Also beware of the whitespace in the program